# Product rule for higher powers of the Laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\Delta$ be the Laplacian to a metric with arbitrary signature and denote by $\Delta^k=\underbrace{\Delta\circ\dots\circ\Delta}_{k-\textrm{times}}$. For $k=1$ there is a product formula for $\Delta(f\cdot g)$. Is there a formula for
$$
\Delta^k(f\cdot g)
$$
too? (of course we assume that $f$ and $g$ are sufficiently often differentiable)

Comment: Context? For example, might you mean to have a product rule for $\Delta$ by having a Dirac operator $\mathbb D$ such that $\mathbb D^2=\Delta$? (Or $-\Delta$?) In that case (for example) there are issues with the non-commutativity of the Clifford-algebra coefficients of $\mathbb D$...

Comment: I am thinking for example of the euclidean or minkowski Laplacian. So you say it is not possible to have such a formula?

Comment: There are certainly difficulties, apart from signature, already "locally", too. (One alternative one might imagine is to use a square root of $-\Delta$ as unbounded operator, but then it won't have a Leibniz' rule, which is what I presume you mean by "product formula".) That is, a Dirac operator produces an output which takes values in the associated (almost always non-commutative) Clifford algebra (e.g., quaternions and such), so any sort of product rule has to accommodate the non-commutative _scalars_...